# Vim Color Scheme for ARM Assembly files

Tags: assembly, vim, arm

Is there a way to get my default color sheme (or any color scheme really) for ARM assembly files? I really just want syntax coloring for the commands and the registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax highlighting for ARM has been done here: https://github.com/ARM9/arm-syntax-vim

The contribution here is an enumeration of keyword you don't want to repeat. Example:

```
" Registers
syn match armRegister "\<R\%(1[0-5]\|[0-9]\)\>"
syn match armRegister "\<C\%(1[0-5]\|[0-9]\)\>"
syn match armRegister "\<P\%(1[0-5]\|[0-9]\)\>"
syn keyword armRegister FP SP LR PC SPSR CPSR CPSR_c CPSR_cxsf BP
syn match armRegister "\<A[1-3]\>"
syn match armRegister "\<V[1-8]\>"

" Conditional field to avoid repetition
let armCond = '\%(AL\|CC\|CS\|EQ\|GE\|GT\|HI\|HS\|LE\|LO\|LS\|LT\|MI\|NE\|PL\|VC\|VS\)\?'

"
" ARMv4 and thumb instructions
" 
exec 'syn match armv4Instr "\%(ADC\|ADD\|AND\|ASR\|BIC\|EOR\|LSL\|LSR\|MLA\|MOV\|MUL\|MVN\|NEG\|ORR\|ROR\|RRX\|RSB\|RSC\|SBC\|SMLAL\|SMULL\|SUB\|UMLAL\|UMULL\)' . armCond . 'S\?\>"'

exec 'syn match armv4InstrCond  "\%(B\|BL\|BX\|CDP\|CMN\|CMP\|LDC\|MCR\|MRC\|MRS\|MSR\|NOP\|POP\|PUSH\|STC\|SWI\|TEQ\|TST\)' . armCond . '\>"'
```